# Flexbox content not spreading evenly with links and images

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm using flex to build footer. I want the footer to be 60% of the width of the website and centered which is working perfectly. When I add content into the footer of text, links, and image links and try to justify space-evenly it doesn't work properly and there is a lot of extra white space on the right side within the footer. How do I remove it?

[Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gFlO.png)

CSS

```
    .site-wide-footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<footer>
 <div class="site-wide-footer">
   <p>&copy; 2018 copyright</p>
   <p><a href="store.html" class="button-footer"> &diams;STORE</a></p>
   <p><a href="about-us.html" class="button-footer">&diams;ABOUT US</a></p>
   <p><a href="sitemap.xml" class="button-footer">&diams;SITEMAP</a></p>
  <div class="social-footer">
   <p><a href="discord url">
   <img src="images/Discord-Logo-White.png" alt="Discord Logo" 
   class="discord-footer" onmouseover="hover(this);" 
   onmouseout="unhover(this);"></a>
   <a href="facebook url/"><img 
   src="images/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Icon" class="facebook- 
   footer"></a></p>
  </div>  
 </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `justify-content: space-evenly;` instead? It will also make sure the the child elements are still centered even when it is wrapped over to the next line.

Comment: space-evenly makes the content event tighter together. When I look at it with the firefox dev tools it shows that the two image links fill the entire space to the right. I tried giving them a margin of 0 and even margin-right of 0 to try to remove the space but it had no effect.

Comment: That seems to be caused by the <div class="social-footer"> and <p> tag surrounding both images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to consider setting a `flex` rule for the flex-box children.
I'm not sure I understand what exactly you try to achive, but if you play with this `flex` rule, you can achieve a lot.

```
.site-wide-footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-around; /*you can play with it*/
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 15px 0; /*fixed space on left and right of the flex-box*/
}
.site-wide-footer > { /*flex-box children */
    flex: 1 0; /*play with this one a bit. you could also give it a minimum width like that:  flex: 1 0 100px;*/
}`
```

And of course, you may find all the answers on this [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Itamar